# Nvidia failed after kernel update

Tags: nvidia, kernel, updates, graphics, ubuntu-studio

Whenever I reach the kernel (5.4.0-65) update on ubuntu 20.04 the nvidia driver gets wrong.
This is the fourth time I have to reinstall ubuntu because no matter what similar question I follow to solve it allways ends wrong because I know the "basics" of ubuntu but the graphics stuff surpasses me.

I know that this question is already on the forum but I can't follow all of the steps properly so I would like anyone to help me.

I don't know what information do I have to post you. I had applyied the 460 nvidia driver from the "drivers" not downloaded from nvidia.

Thanks in advance

Edited for adding information:

As @Pilot6 sugested I booted in a previous Kernel because there may be an bug on the present kernel:

Results: I have managed to unistall the nvidia drivers with an older kernel, use the X.org Nouveau driver so the computer has a better resolution. In the other hand, the reinstalation of the nvidia driver that I want and need for working with blender it is pointless because no matter how I try to reinstall it the server allways appears empty and I loose the resolution that I had with X.org

Stepts needed:
(advise: I am not an experienced on linux, just try what I found in Internet, recieve the errors and look for solutions on the Internet again)

1 edit the grub file to modify some values:
type: ctrl + alt + t simultaneously to get into the terminal.
in the terminal type this: `sudo mousepad /etc/default/grub`
modify the document only in this lines. do not touch any other thing.

modify the line when it says GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden   to GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu

modify the line when it says GRUB_TIMEOUT=0 to GRUB_TIMEOUT=10

add this line  `GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep` to the document save and close

type `sudo update-grub` on the terminal and reboot the computer

once you enter the system and you can see the grub menu go to advanced options with arrow keys and start the machine with an older kernel but not in recovery mode.

Once you log in go to more drivers and choose the X.org Nouveau driver and restart the machine.

Now I have a normal resolution. how can I reinstall the nvidia drivers?

what have not results at all:

- install it with the more drivers app.
- type in a terminal  `sudo apt update; sudo apt upgrade; sudo apt autoremove` and try to reinstall the drivers on the more drivers app
- `sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current; sudo apt-get install nvidia-current`

So what do I do now? what info can I post you to help me. Thanks again.

Comment: What is Ubuntu 20.20?

Comment: sorry, mistake. it is ubuntu 20.04.2

Comment: what happens after the kernel update it is that the nvidia server shows itself empty and the resolution has minimized to 1024x786 and there is no other resolution.

Comment: Can you explain it a bit better? You install the system, install the driver, then reboot and all works, doesn't it? You install kernel updates and Nvidia stops working. Is it correct?

Comment: what happens after the kernel update it is that the nvidia server shows itself empty and the resolution has minimized to 1024x786 and there is no other resolution.

Comment: I have been using the distribution 20.04.2 for three months and today when I reach the kernel distribution the system said that it was needed to restart the system and when I booted again that happened. Nvidia server empty, and no more resolution than that 1024x786. I have tried to unistall the driver not from comand but nothing happen.

Comment: Boot with a previous kernel. There may be a bug in this kernel.

Comment: may be? how do I boot in a previous kernel? Has that step an easy way back?

Comment: Nevermind, I have to give up for now. I will look for the sugestion of boot in a previous kernel, but not today. Thank you @pilot6.

Comment: I have tried to boot on older kernel pressing shift as it boots. Nothing. I have modified the /etc/default/grub to put timeout and countdown but it says a file is missing. Anyway,

Comment: Anyway, I can see that in "more drivers" program there is the driver 460 metapackage but when I try to purge all nvidia stuff it says that I do not have the nvidia driver  instaled. But, when I try to install it via terminal, it says that the nvidia package it is not avaliable but another package refers to him. So, the nvida package has not a candidate for the instalation. I've got a geforce gtx 960.

Comment: I have tried to reinstall the driver:

Comment: I finally manage to boot in a prior kernel and nothing has happen

Comment: choosing he older kernel I manage to uninstall the nvidia driver and I am working with noveau. But this is not a solution for me because I needed the nvidia drivers to work with blender. I try to install the nvidia drivers from the more drivers app and does not work. any sugestions?

Comment: Maybe [NVIDIA support](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/support/) can help?

Comment: Ok. I will look for help there. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to make the nvidia driver 460 work again on Version 20.04.2 LTS Focal Fossa (Xfce Desktop)

first off it all, I have not too much experience. At your own risk, just followed troubleshooting part of the link. I have explained how I managed to restore the noveau driver for the resolution stuff in the previous post and I do not know if this is necesary to reinstall the nvidia drivers at all. You may jump that and try the next step rough.

Check this link and go to the troubleshooting part:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

what i have done:

1 Install synaptics.

2 install the linux-headers-xxx
xxx= the version of the kernel you have and you can check it with `uname -a`

3 Install the nvidia driver from synaptics.
If you don't know wich of them to install run in a terminal `sudo ubuntu-drivers devices` and check for 'recomended one' and install it.

Note: I don't know wwhat's the difference between a normal driver and the server one. I have installed the normal one.

5 reboot

Now you should have the nvida driver installed but the server setings are not going to work (empty) so:

6 run `sudo prime-select nvidia` it said that nvidia driver was choosen but i write it here because I don't know if this is important.

7 run twice `sudo nvidia-xconfig`
the first gives you error and the second one it's done. it works like that.

8  run `sudo update-initramfs -u` in a terminal.

9 reboot

10 enter in a terminal and type `nvidia-settings` and if the message ir is that prime it is not and the window appears empty again then you need to load the modules before so close the window and edit the /etc/modules with sudo and add this to the file:

nvidia

nvidia-drm

nvidia-modeset

save the changes and type `sudo update-initramfs -u`

And that was all. It is working for now.

final note: long live to the synaptics creators! long live to the ubuntu comunity! thanks for you all.