# Can't install updated kernel headers,Nvidia driver setup fails

Tags: drivers, nvidia, kernel

I have been struggling with getting NVIDIA driver installation due to the kernel upgrade.

I updated the kernel from 5.13 on Ubuntu 20.04 to 5.16 because the original one didn't recognize wifi and bluetooth adapters. I used [this manual](https://nextgentips.com/2021/12/14/how-to-upgrade-linux-kernel-on-ubuntu-20-04-to-5-16-release/). After that my NVIDIA driver has disappeared and I have been trying to get it back since then without success. Where

> without success

means that the installation finishes,but no smi and no nvidia-settings are set.

Here is what I have tried so far:

1. First,I tried purging anything by NVIDIA, reinstalled many times,different versions etc.
   It all ends up with:

   ```
   NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate
   with the NVIDIA driver.
   Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and
   running.
   ```
2. Then I was reading that maybe the kernel headers don not exist or not installed properly. I have checked `dpkg-query -s linux-headers-generic` :

   ```
   Package: linux-headers-generic Status: install ok installed Priority:optional Section: kernel Installed-Size: 19 Maintainer:
   Ubuntu Kernel
   Team <kernel-team@lists.ubuntu.com> Architecture: amd64 Source:
   linux-meta Version: 5.4.0.117.120 Depends:
   linux-headers-5.4.0-117-generic Description: Generic Linux kernel
   headers  This package will always depend on the latest generic kernel
   headers  available.
   ```

Weird,because I am running on kernel: `5.16.0-051600rc5-generic`

3. Then I checked with this command:`apt list linux-headers*`:

   ```
   Listing... Error! E: input:0-68: error: Expected pattern   
   linux-headers-5.16.0-051600rc5_5.16.0-051600rc5.202112121931_all.deb
   ```
4. Then I tried to install the related headers,`sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)`
   :

   ```
    Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
    Reading state information... Done Package
    linux-headers-5.16.0-051600rc5-generic is not available, but is
    referred to by another package. This may mean that the package
    is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from
    another source

    E: Package 'linux-headers-5.16.0-051600rc5-generic' has no
    installation candidate
   ```
5. Also,if I run this `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic`
   I am getting:

   ```
    Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
    Reading state information... Done linux-headers-generic
    is already the newest version (5.4.0.117.120).
    0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
   ```

But I am not running on that kernel.

`dkms status`:

```
backport-iwlwifi, 8324: added
nvidia, 510.73.08: added
rtbth, 3.9.7, 5.13.0-48-generic, x86_64: installed
rtbth, 3.9.7, 5.4.0-117-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au, 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg, 5.13.0-44-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au, 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg, 5.13.0-48-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8812au, 4.3.8.12175.20140902+dfsg, 5.16.0-051600rc5-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu, 5.8.7.1, 5.13.0-44-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu, 5.8.7.1, 5.13.0-48-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl88x2bu, 5.8.7.1, 5.4.0-117-generic, x86_64: installed
```

If I run `sudo nvidia-settings`  after installing the driver I am getting this:

```
ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded

(nvidia-settings:4568): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 12:23:00.499: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

** (nvidia-settings:4568): CRITICAL **: 12:23:00.499: ctk_powermode_new: assertion '(ctrl_target != NULL) && (ctrl_target->h != NULL)' failed

ERROR: nvidia-settings could not find the registry key file or the X server is not accessible. This file should have been installed along with this driver at
       /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation. The application profiles will continue to work, but values cannot be prepopulated or validated,
       and will not be listed in the help text. Please see the README for possible values and descriptions.
```

I have also tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1314783/nvidia-failed-after-kernel-update) and a bunch of other voodoo, but I am at the same place.I fill like there is a problem with how I install the kernel and the headers. I also tried the same thing with 5.18 ,but it ends up with the same issues.

Comment: Did you install headers for the 5.16 kernel? You can't install headers using the command you tried to run, because these headers don't exist in Ubuntu repos. Also Nvidia drivers may not be built on the 5.16 kernel too. Make sure you install headers properly.

Comment: Also please format text with `{}` icon.

Comment: Sorry,the first link was wrong.I have installed the update using this article: https://nextgentips.com/2021/12/14/how-to-upgrade-linux-kernel-on-ubuntu-20-04-to-5-16-release/

Comment: So did you install headers? It is p.2 of the manual. Also please add output of `dkms status` to your question. PLEASE format it properly.

Comment: It does format. You don't type `{` and `}`, but click the `{}` icon above the text input field.

Comment: `apt list linux-headers` should not show anything. Please add output of `dkms status` to your question. Please don't format it, and I will show it for you. Your formatting is breakng lines and it is very hard to undo.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and I guess it might be caused by a failed `linux-headers-5.16.0-051600rc5-generic` installation. You can try adding Ubuntu 22.04 repo to solve the headers installation dependency problem. For more information on how to install this headers please refer to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/685830/how-to-use-5-16-kernel-with-ubuntu-21-10/691959#691959?newreg=9d33b485afbd4d4e99a8b872015bc8b3:~:text=8-,Here%27s%20how%20I%20got%20it%20to%20work%2C%20it%27s%20similar%20to%20%40airium%27s%20answer%20but%20with%20the%20exact%20commands%20I%20used%3A,-